# How to return multiple values in powershell from SQL query

Tags: sql, powershell

I use Powershell embedded in an application to get some database values back. The SQL Query can have multiple values. I got the code to work to return me a single value. But I don't seem to get more than one record back (or I am unable to access it). And, I am also not able to use .Count to see the number of records.

This code works for a single DB record:

```
            $conn=New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SQLConnection("Persist Security Info=True;Initial Catalog=;Data Source=;User ID=;Password=;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;")
            $conn.Open() | out-null
            $cmd1=$conn.CreateCommand()
            $cmd1.CommandType = [System.Data.CommandType]::Text
            $cmd1.CommandText = ("SELECT Supplier_Code FROM V_SUPPLIERINFO WHERE ACN='" + $Context.File.Field[10] + "'")
            $reader = $cmd1.ExecuteReader()
            #LOOP THROUGH RECORDS
            for ($i=0; $i -lt $cmd1.Count; $i++){
            }   
            $Context.File.Notes = "I have past the File Note - Count Script: " + $cmd1.Count
            $reader.Read() | out-null
            $Context.File.Field[11] = $reader.GetString(0)
            $Context.File.Save()
            return "done"
```

Now, I would like to loop through all the results. Ideally I use something like $reader.count to get the number of results returned. However, .count always returns 1.

I tried the code below to get the count separately:
$conn=New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SQLConnection("Persist Security Info=True;Initial Catalog=;Data Source=;User ID=;Password=;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;")
                $conn.Open() | out-null

```
            $SQLRecordCount=$conn.CreateCommand()
            $SQLRecordCount.CommandType = [System.Data.CommandType]::Text
            $SQLRecordCount.CommandText = ("SELECT COUNT (Supplier_Code) FROM V_SUPPLIERINFO WHERE ACN='" + $Context.File.Field[10] + "'")
            $reader = $SQLRecordCount.ExecuteReader()

            $reader.Read() | out-null
            $Context.File.Notes = "Total DB Records: " + $reader.GetString(0)

            $cmd1=$conn.CreateCommand()
            $cmd1.CommandType = [System.Data.CommandType]::Text
            $cmd1.CommandText = ("SELECT Supplier_Code FROM V_SUPPLIERINFO WHERE ACN='" + $Context.File.Field[10] + "'")
            $reader = $cmd1.ExecuteReader()

            #$Context.File.Notes = "Total DB Records: " + $cmd1.length

            #LOOP THROUGH RECORDS
            for ($i=0; $i -lt $cmd1.Count; $i++){
            }   

            $reader.Read() | out-null
            $Context.File.Field[11] = $reader.GetString(0)
            $Context.File.Save()
            return "done"
```

But that always returns the value 1.

Any idea how I get the number of records found or how I can loop through the records?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should be looking at $reader rather than $cmd1. [This MSDN blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/buckwoody/2009/04/13/run-a-sql-server-command-from-powershell-without-the-sql-server-provider/) shows an similar example to what you are trying to do.

From the post:

```
# Create and open a database connection
$sqlConnection = new-object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection “server=SERVERNAME\INSTANCE;database=AdventureWorks;Integrated Security=sspi”
$sqlConnection.Open()

#Create a command object
$sqlCommand = $sqlConnection.CreateCommand()

$sqlCommand.CommandText = “select FirstName, LastName from Person.Contact where LastName like 'W%'”

#Execute the Command
$sqlReader = $sqlCommand.ExecuteReader()

#Parse the records
while ($sqlReader.Read()) { $sqlReader[“LastName”] + “, ” + $sqlReader[“FirstName”]}

# Close the database connection
$sqlConnection.Close()
```

Comment: Thanks BenH, the Parsing part with while did the trick. Then I also don't need the count.

Answer (score 0):

Change $reader = $cmd1.ExecuteReader()
TO: $reader = $cmd1.ExecuteReader([System.Data.CommandBehavior]::CloseConnection)

Then to iterate over the column values simply call

$reader | ForEach-Object { $_.Item('Supplier_Code') }

Answer (score 0):

You are really doing things the hard way there....
I would suggest using the built-in powershell `Invoke-Sqlcmd` or use a module I developed called [InvokeQuery](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/InvokeQuery/0.9.1), which is much more flexible and powerful. Either way you'll get back a proper powershell array which is then trivial to perform counts and iterate through the results.  It's also far fewer lines of code.

```
#Install-Module -Name InvokeQuery
$server = "mysqlserver.mydomain.com"
$db = "mydatabaseName"
$params = @{ "ACN"=$Context.File.Field[10] }
$sql = "SELECT Supplier_Code FROM V_SUPPLIERINFO WHERE ACN=@ACN;" 
$results = Invoke-SqlServerQuery -Sql $sql -Server $server -Database $db -Parameters $params
# now getting a count is trivial
Write-Host "Returned $($results.count) rows."
# and you can use standard powershell formatting to view the data in table format:
$results | ft
```

Also, if you're only retrieving a single value from a db query, as in your second code block, you don't need to use a reader, you can use the ExecuteScalar method and it'll return the value of the first column of the first row. My powershell module has a similar switch for that as well:

```
## same code as above.
$sql = "SELECT count(*) FROM V_SUPPLIERINFO WHERE ACN=@ACN;" 
$count = Invoke-SqlServerQuery -Sql $sql -Server $server -Database $db -Parameters $params -Scalar
Write-Host "The row count is $count."
```